# ostream& does not name a type error. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

I am a learner. I am working on operator overloading. I am trying to write a code for overloading [] and print the elements in the member array. But when I am overloading << to print the member array, I get the error, *ostream& does not have a type*. What am I doing wrong here? Also what can I do if I have a class that has two member arrays? Here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
class Digit
{
private:
    int digit1[3]{0};

public:    
    int& operator[](const int index);

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out);
};

int& Digit::operator[](const int index)
{
    return digit1[index];
}

ostream& Digit::operator<<(ostream& out)
{
    int loop;
    out << "{";
    for (loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
    {
        out << digit1[loop] << " ";
    }
    out << "}";

    return o;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Digit n;
    n[0] = 4;
    n[1] = 3;
    n[2] = 4;


    n << cout;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably just missing the namespace `std::ostream`

Comment: The overload should be a free function so you can follow the standard pattern `cout << n;`.

Comment: `operator<<` should not be a member function. You want to write `stream << object`, not `object << stream`

Answer (score 2):

You have put

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    //....
```

This cannot be seen where you declare your `<<` operator. One solution is to change the signature to include the namesape:

In the class:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out)
```

and then

```
std::ostream& Digit::operator<<(std::ostream& out)
```

While you are there, I wonder if it should be `const`?

Comment: That worked. But still, when the member variable is not an array. it worked without the above namespace. why is that?

Comment: You  need to ask a new question, posting the exact code that failed.

Answer (score 0):

you must be forgetting the namespace
try - std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.